# name for a matrix decomposition $T^{-1} S T$ (S lower and T upper triangular)

Tags: matrix-decomposition

A given real square matrix $M$ has a decomposition

$M = T^{-1} S T$

where $S$ and $T$ are lower and resp. upper triangular with '$1$'s in the diagonal. Does this type of decomposition have a known classification/name? I could not find something similar under
the wikipedia entry for matrix decomposition.

Thank you

Comment: It's something like a special type of Jordan decomposition. I'm not aware of a name.

Comment: ... according to this [source](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/Schur-decomposition), it could also be a Schur decomposition where however $S$ is upper triangular. In the case here $S$ is lower triangular but I imagine that it is easy to change a Schur decomposition so that it fits the latter?

Comment: Sure. (Hah.) As for flipping triangularity, just do a Schur decomposition of $M^\top$ and transpose afterwards.

Comment: I see...so assuming that M has the decomposition above where S is upper triangular, then $M^{\top}=(T^{-1}S T)^{\top}=(ST)^{\top}(T^{-1})^{\top}=T^{\top} S^{\top} (T^{\top})^{-1}$. Hence there is a corresponding lower triangular decomposition!! Thank you